# Are we attracted towards Earth just because of Gravity?

Tags: electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, coulombs-law

We think that we are just attracted to earth due to gravity but what about the charge of our body and negative potential of Earth does we have no attraction due to charge?

Comment: If we were not at the same potential at the earth, we would discharge as soon as we touch it (think lightning).

Comment: Sorry sir the negative potential of earth is not zero its actually  -35 volts at 100 feet depth and increases as we go deeper in crust

Comment: you are right but we actually discharge almost 0.68 watt per day into gnd  @hdhondt

Comment: You are in contact with Earth continuously and lead current enough well to be on the same potential.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule humans carry only a small charge. That's because humans are conductors and we are usually in electrical equilibrium with our surroundings. If you've ever had a static shock after walking on a nylon carpet you have experienced this equilibrating process in action.

So while you are quite correct that electrostatic forces could in principle modify the net force we feel, in practice this doesn't happen to any significant extent.

Comment: take a sensitive voltmeter and check potential difference between gnd and your body you will definitely change your answer

Comment: @FaisalIqbalBaba: *take a sensitive voltmeter* - that's precisely the point. If humans possessed a significant charge the voltmeter wouldn't need to be sensitive.